# Anchor-Div not scrolling to the right place in firefox only

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, scroll, routes, anchor

I'm absolutely stuck here and hoping someone here will have the answer.

ok - The end goal is to be redirected to another page and be placed at the beginning of a certain DIV. I'm using an anchor tag which points to a DIV with an ID attached to it.
My code works for all browsers EXCEPT for Firefox??

Link on page one:

```
    <a href="/home/services#design">
      <%= image_tag "Read_More_Button.png", :alt => "", :style => 
      "position:relative;   left:-10px"%>
    -close a tag
```

Div with content on page 2:

```
    <div id='design' class='left clear_right '>  
      more <div>'s nested and a unordered list.  black as well. 
    -close div tag
```

The route in my config/routes.rb:

```
    get "home/services" => "home#services"
```

To see how this is currently working please see online version link:

[website_link] http://mearsinteriors.co.uk/ "click here for website"

Click on the "read more" button for Design or fitout and you'll see that you aren't taken to the top of either div but the route/url in the address bar is correctly pointing to this location? This only happens in Firefox, I have tried in safe mode and disabled all add ons and still nothing.

any adice or direction would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: This is strange! Oddly enough, both links end up scrolling to the same position on the page. Disabling javascript fixes the issue! Your .js file is minified so couldn't see what it is, but there is something going on in there that messes up scroll.

Comment: You solved my problem but I don't know why, this is what I did.
commented out the javascript and saw my large images(5 of them being displayed one underneath the other). now the position of the bottom of the last image is round about the same position the page scrolls to on the 2nd page when the read more link is clicked. 

I had img_tags listed without any containers(no span tags).

As soon as I added the span tags ... bam!  worked like a charm.
Thanks a million.  Your comment lead to my solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the Jquery cycle library I was using. Each image's container was still being spaced out over the page. so even though the images weren't visible the divs were still there. Hence the reason the page scroll to the exact position no mater the anchor being directed to.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! So you wrapped your images in `<span>` tags and that fixed their visibility, correct? You can mark this as the solution :)